# Split double quotes comma double quotes in java

Tags: java, split

I am new to programming and I am stuck in the below requirement. I need to split the below using java. There are multiple lines like this in the csv file

```
INPUT: "EmpID","User ID","First Name","Location","Last Name","JobCode"
```

Save the above to a array and display the Output as below

```
OUTPUT: First Name_Last Name : "EmpID","User ID","First Name","Location","Last Name","JobCode"
```

Here is my code:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] parts = line.split(",", 4);
    if (parts.length >= 4) {
        String key = parts[2] + "_" + parts[4];
        map.put(key, line);
    }
}
```

How to use split in this case?

Comment: Use a library with a CSV Parser.

Comment: Or convert it with `[` and `]` to **JSON** and use a JSON-Parser...

Comment: Thank you @Adrian Preuss for your response. Is it possible to try with Regex ?

Comment: Yes, it is - For sample: `(:?["]+)?(?<value>[^"]+)"(:?[,\s]+)`. See https://regex101.com/r/0gclto/1/ for an example.